# Why are all non-Euclidean geometries quadratic?

Tags: normed-spaces, quadratic-forms, noneuclidean-geometry

The non-Euclidean geometries are both based on conic sections: Elliptic and Hyperbolic.  Conic sections are described with 2nd-degree polynomials.

Are there any geometries based on higher degree polynomials?  If not, why is the number 2 so special?  e.g. It might be because there is no 3rd-degree analog of the Pythagorean theorem, but I have never found a good explanation about why this is the case.

Comment: I suppose the names are related to the metrics on those spaces. A metric is a bilinear form. If you want something of higher degree, you will have to consider trilinear forms. I don't know if that is a common research topic.

Comment: Also, this might interest you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're willing to call a "geometry." There are, for example, $\ell^p$ spaces for any $p \ge 1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thank you for the wikipedia link.  This indeed seems to suggest that there is something fundamentally "easier" about 2D than 3D.  It is not yet clear to me what the fundamental difference might be.  A quick search for "trilinear form" yields little useful information.  I will keep searching starting from your feedback.  Thanks!

Comment: Even if you stay within 2D geometry, there are beasts that are quite different from Elliptic, Euclidian and Hyperbolic geometry. Take for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_plane

Comment: I remember when I studied algebra and we came across the notion of a group, I asked a very similar question. If we can study an operation on two elements, why not study operations on three elements and define a structure? It's certainly possible and has probably been done. But does it lead to interesting mathematics? Lots of stuff is possible to think up, but they don't always lead to interesting avenues. And there's also fashion phenomena that have to be taken into account.

Comment: @Raskolnikov My prof told me a story about a small group of Polish(?) mathematicians who devised a new mathematical structure with a few simple axioms/properties. They wrote paper after paper exploring these new things, deriving ever more outlandish theorems about them. It all collapsed when it turned out that the axioms were somewhat contradictory so that no non-trivial examples of this structure actually existed. I don't know if there is actually any truth to this story, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: To get back to the original question, I think the closest I can think of is the theory of algebraic surfaces and specifically of cubic surfaces.